# when user search movie name by enter letter/letters it is showing only one (last) movie name and give resource type error?

Tags: java, android, okhttp

i am taking data from cinemalytics server and showing in listview but last movie name showing multiple time...
taking data from server
moviename = new ArrayList<>();
    Currentmovie c = new Currentmovie();

```
JSONArray values = new JSONArray(json);
for(int i = 0; i < values.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = values.getJSONObject(i);

    String movieTitle = jsonObject.getString("Title");
    Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);

    c.setTitle(movieTitle);
    moviename.add(c);
    //binding through adapter
     mAdapter = new MovieAdapter
               (getApplicationContext(),moviename);
                lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Error Logcat:----

```
Failure getting entry for 0x010804e0 (t=7 e=1248) (error -75)
06-23 07:37:00.075 5141-5164/com.example.maau.movieinfo W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x0108051f (t=7 e=1311) (error -75)
06-23 07:37:00.075 5141-5164/com.example.maau.movieinfo W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080027 (t=7 e=39) (error -75)
06-23 07:37:00.075 5141-5164/com.example.maau.movieinfo W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080403 (t=7 e=1027) (error -75)
06-23 07:37:00.075 5141-5164/com.example.maau.movieinfo W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x010802ae (t=7 e=686) (error -75)
06-23 07:37:00.076 5141-5164/com.example.maau.movieinfo W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x01080276 (t=7 e=630) (error -75)
```

Comment: in log it shows all movie name......

Comment: I see that you are parsing APIs by yourself. You can also use official SDK to do that: github.com/Cinemalytics/CinemalyticsJavaSDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);

c.setTitle(movieTitle);
```

with

```
Log.e(TAG,"GIRISH"+movieTitle);
c = new Currentmovie();
c.setTitle(movieTitle);
```

The reason is that you only once create a movie, and then add same movie to the list multiple times. Each time you add it again, you set a new name to it. But since the list contains the same object multiple times, the title of all list items is the same - the last one you've set to object

Comment: @GIRISHPUROHIT, that is a very programming basics. It will take me few hours to explain, so better just find some lesson about objects and references

Comment: @GIRISHPUROHIT, you create only one object. And then change it's name multiple times. Result is that it's name is the last one you set to it. Your list contains multiple referenses to the same object.